# Mono 3.0.6 - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mono, centos

I'm running Mono 3.0.6 on CentOS 6. I've published an ASP.NET 4.0/MVC4 website on it, and after ironing out some compatibility issues, I've met a wall. Whenever I try to access the application, I get this error:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
```

I think this is due to the fact that Mono uses EF6, but this is still Alpha and so Microsoft bundles EF5. What would be the most elegant, least 'hackish' way of fixing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what is the **file** that is *not found*.

For that, you could use the env vars `MONO_LOG_MASK="asm"` and `MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug"`, explained [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Logging_Runtime_Events).